# Profiling a Rust application in CLion takes very long

Tags: rust, profiling, clion, perf

I have a Rust program, that I wish to profile to find potential bottlenecks in performance.
To do this, I use `perf` as my profiler (I use linux with the `5.15.0-52-generic` kernel) and th builtin profiling option in CLion.
I did run the program with the `--release` flag enabled and attached perf to it directly inside the IDE. The program ran succesfully (Taking approx. 1 minute, on 8 threads (4 hyperthreaded cores) with almost 100% cpu usage most of the time), but after it finished, CLion is taking ages to read the profiling data (it has been doing this for about 20hours now).

Why is this taking so long and is there a way to speed this up? The project lies on an older HDD drive, which CLion probably also uses to store the profiling data on. Is that the bottleneck here?

For comparison, I used `flamegraph` to compare how long it would take to profile the program. It also took quite long, but less than an hour, not 20 hours.

Comment: Clion is written in java. Maybe it has difficulty processing the large profile on a limited heap, try bumping its max heap size. You could also try reducing the sampling rate to generate smaller profiles.

Comment: Try profiling without CLion to see whether this is a CLion issue. And yes, reducing the sampling rate should keep the profile smaller. Reading a profile shouldn't take more than a few minutes.